# TypeScript: Cannot access a object by variable key

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here my code looks like:

```
export const EMOJI_NAME_KEY = "n";
export const EMOJI_UNICODE_KEY = "u";


export interface Emoji {
  [EMOJI_NAME_KEY]: string[];
  [EMOJI_UNICODE_KEY]: string;
}

const emoji: Emoji = {
   [EMOJI_NAME_KEY]: 'thumb',
   [EMOJI_UNICODE_KEY]: 'some_unicode_key'
}
```

Now whenever I try to access a value from Emoji type, I'm getting an error. For example:

```
console.log(emoji[EMOJI_NAME_KEY]) // returns error in the terminal like below
```

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type 'Emoji'.   No index signature
> with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Emoji'

Comment: You should declare emoji as `const emoji: Emoji = {
   [EMOJI_NAME_KEY]: ['thumb'],
   [EMOJI_UNICODE_KEY]: 'some_unicode_key'
}`. Notice the array for Name key

Comment: Here's your code in the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wKIFkDyApASQH0A5AQSwyIGkMBNOAXjgCJkWBuAWAChRJYiFOjjZ8xAKokCAYRwARKrQbMWAV069e-aPACWyGMCgAzAIYJgogLYQAVnrgBvXnDgBtMYVIUl9ALoAXHDoUAYA5u7+HHAA9LFwACoAFnqocGlwZshZUFBmAJ5wECYhMGHI4aiuHl6S0nKKNAHBoRHcPAC+WjxIaPDAtg7BGEOOzC48bp643uSUzXRBcADkMMlq1gBGKwA0cQkAyhBw65moyRBqADYAJnBbVu5rG9sr-hn9wGb3Javrmx2NRm4iIUlkCj8S2CK1QEGswCIamQeiQt0RAGtgAUVrxOh1eH04ddgAA6a4QcIACkG9j0ILmvkW-gAlB0gA) with comments about how to fix it.